# 16.04: Blank space on workspace swicher window[taskbar positioned bottom]

Tags: 16.04, taskbar, workspace-switcher

How to remove the blank space to the left?

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: @DavidFoerster The space to the left. I've modified the image to show it.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for that. I never used Unity myself so I can't tell you any details but you should look into themes for Unity.